# AS3: Can ByteArray return its content as a string with two bytes per unicode character?

Tags: actionscript-3, unicode, encoding, arrays, tostring

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
bytes.writeInt(0);

trace(bytes.length); // prints 4
trace(bytes.toString().length); // prints 4
```

When I run the above code the output suggests that every character in the string returned by toString contains one byte from the ByteArray. This is of course great if you want to display the content of the ByteArray, but not so great if you want to send its content encoded in a string and the size of the string matters.

Is it possible to get a string from the ByteArray where every character in the string contains two bytes from the ByteArray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reinterpret your `ByteArray` as containing only shorts.  This lets you read two bytes at a time and get a single number value representing them both.  Next, you can take these numbers and reinterpret them as being character codes.  Finally, create a `String` from these character codes and you're done.

```
public static function encode(ba:ByteArray):String {
    var origPos:uint = ba.position;
    var result:Array = new Array();

    for (ba.position = 0; ba.position < ba.length - 1; )
        result.push(ba.readShort());

    if (ba.position != ba.length)
        result.push(ba.readByte() << 8);

    ba.position = origPos;
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result);
}
```

There is one special circumstance to pay attention to.  If you try reading a short from a `ByteArray` when there is only one byte remaining in it, an exception will be thrown.  In this case, you should call `readByte` with the value shifted 8 bits instead.  This is the same as if the original `ByteArray` had an extra 0 byte at the end. (making it even in length)

Now, as for decoding this String...  Get the character code of each character, and place them into a new `ByteArray` as shorts.  It will be identical to the original, except if the original had an odd number of bytes, in which case the decoded `ByteArray` will have an extra 0 byte at the end.

```
public static function decode(str:String):ByteArray {
    var result:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        result.writeShort(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    result.position = 0;
    return result;
}
```

In action:

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

ba.writeInt(47);
ba.writeUTF("Goodbye, cruel world!");

var str:String = encode(ba);
ba = decode(str);

trace(ba.readInt());
trace(ba.readUTF());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. You have written a 4 byte int to your ByteArray. You haven't written any characters (unicode or other) to it. If you want to pass text, write text and pass it as UTF8. It will take less space than having two bytes for every character, at least for most western languages.

But honestly, I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to send numbers or text? What backend are you talking to? Do you need a ByteArray at all?