# how to convert a bitmap into a bytearray?

Tags: actionscript-3

i have to save a bitmap in to a sharedobject....I read it online that inorder to do that I would have to convert into a bytearray..but I ma not sure how to do this...can somebody please explain to me a little step by step on how to convert a bitmap into bytearray..

this is the code i am working with

```
var btm:BitmapData;
var x_d:Array = new Array();

orange.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, firstc);
    function firstc (x:MouseEvent){

        btm = new BitmapData(200,200);
       x_d[0] = new Bitmap (btm);
        addChild(x_d[0]);
        btm.draw (orange);
            gotoAndStop(3);

    };
```

Comment: You need to use [`BitmapData.getPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels()).  A good place to start would be a Google search for `BitmapData ByteArray`, which yields helpful examples such as [this](http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/index.php/getpixels).

Answer (score 3):

If you want raw data you should use [getPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels%28%29) method but if you want to store bitmapdata compressed as jpg or png do like this:

**PNG**

```
btm = new BitmapData(200,200);
...
var stream:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( btm );
```

**JPG**

```
btm = new BitmapData(200,200);
...
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder( 90 );
var stream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode( btm );
```

for PNGEncoder and JPGEncoder classes use [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

If you target users with Flash Player 11.3 and above you can use [native encoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#encode%28%29)

Comment: oh I need raw data... so it can save it self in a bytearray upon closing and extract it upon opening (if i understand the method correctly)..umm I looked at the get pixels it takes data and puts it in the byte array but how do I extract it or save the byte array...so far i have a method where i have an array that stores all the variables and it's value and saves it in a cookie ..will I be able to make the bytearray part of that array or will I need to run it separately?

Comment: [How to convert byteArray to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477978/as3-can-bytearray-return-its-content-as-a-string-with-two-bytes-per-unicode-cha)